# Websockets on Kamailio + sipml5 + rtpproxy-ng + jitsi

Tags: voip

I need quick help with pointing direction on what I should look at - I got Jitsi with Kamailio up and working both signaling and RTP streaming now I got Kamailio with ws:// setuped and sipml5 working instance where I can log into Kamailio - I can call from sipml5 to jitsi client but I don't have any RTP stream communication between those two - should I look into rtpproxy-ng and sipmediaproxy projects? Is that right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes since media in webrtc is by default, peer to peer , and if the endpoints do not support the same codes , you definitely need a media server that acts like a trans-coder . you also need the rtpproxy module in kamilio to force the rtp to proxy through a media server .